# if too much condition Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this code

```
if(beforeModify.get(i).equals("a")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("e")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("i")|
                    beforeModify.get(i).equals("o")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("u")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("á")|
                    beforeModify.get(i).equals("é")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("í")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("ě")|
                    beforeModify.get(i).equals("y")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("ý")|beforeModify.get(i).equals("ů")|
                    beforeModify.get(i).equals("ú"))
```

Can I do it better?

Comment: offtopic: your **OR** condition is not doing what you think it should....

Answer (score 12):

You can write it as a `List.contains` call:

```
if (Arrays.asList("a", "e", etc).contains(beforeModify.get(i))
```

But you could also pre-build a `Set`, and use that:

```
// Build once, keep the set to reuse.
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "e", etc));

if (set.contains(beforeModify.get(i))
```

The `HashSet` has the advantage of being `O(1)` in the number of elements; a `List` would be `O(n)`.

---

Also: you are using `|`, rather than `||`. The former will evaluate *all* operands, the latter will stop as soon as one of them is matched. You don't need to evaluate them all, as `String.equals` on a literal parameter has no side effect. Use `||`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution of [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151644/5558072) here also other solutions using String instead of a List of Set :

Solution 1

```
String str = "aeiouáéíěyýůú";//put the characters you want to check in a string
String s = "z";
//you can use String.contains
if (s.length() == 1 && str.contains(s)) {
    //...
}
```

Solution 2

```
//you can also use replaceAll non that char to check if it is correct or not
if (s.length() == 1 && !str.replaceAll("[^" + s + "]", "").isEmpty()) {
    //...
}
```

Solution 3

```
// You can either use matches
if (str.matches(".*" + s + ".*")) {
    //...
}
```

#### ideon demo

Comment: Solution 2 does not match the specification. It will match something like `aa` or `eé`. Solution 1 also has similar problems (matches `áéí` for instance).

Comment: thank you @Phylogenesis for `aa` or `eé` check this https://ideone.com/kuD16u and for `áéí` the OP should use only one char or check the length before use the solution for example `s.length() == 1 && str.contains(s)`

Comment: @Phylogenesis you can check my answer now i think it is correct now

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is classical case for a switch:

```
switch(beforeModify.get(i)) {
    case "a":
    case "e":
// etc... 
}
```

it looks also more readable and performs as fast as your if

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Isn't String in Switch supported since Java 7?

Comment: @tobias_k - You are correct - my bad. Deleting comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use match() method for regex

```
String input = beforeModify.get(i);
if(input.matches("a*e*i*o*u*á*é*í*ě*y*ý*ů*ú*") && input.length()==1)

or you could just use

if(input.matches("[aeiouáéíěyýůú]"))
```

Comment: Doesn't do the same thing: this would match `aaaeeeiiiooo`, but OP's code wouldn't match that, it only matches a 1-length string.

Comment: I have also added a condition of length i.e. input.length()==1 , so aaaeeeiiiooo will not get a true value in the if condition. Can you help in finding the cases that don't work

Comment: Why not `matches("[aei...]")`?

Comment: Sure that will also work and its shorter too! I'm modifying my answer. Thanks for your input @tobias_k

Comment: When working with a RegEx, you may do the length check with the RegEx itself: `[aeiouáéíěyýůú]{1}`.

Comment: You can, but in this case `{1}` is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using java 8 streams.

```
beforeModify.stream()
.filter(x -> x.matches("[aeiouáéíěyýůú]"))
.forEach(x -> {

    /* Your code here */

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve it with an regular expression using the [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String str = beforeModify.get(i);
if (str.matches("[aeiouáéíěyýůú]") {
    // do whatever you wanna do
}
```

Also calling `beforeModify.get(i)` over and over again is not necessary as it probably yields the same result.